# Call a Hub in another class

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I get an error of:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubContext`1[Common.RfidHub]' while attempting to activate 'Rfid.RfidEngine'.'

on the part of `var rfidEngine = serviceProvider.GetService<IRfidEngine>();`

I have this code:

**Start**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR();
    var collection = new ServiceCollection();
    collection.AddScoped<IApplicationLogger, ApplicationLogger>();
    collection.AddScoped<IRfidEngine, RfidEngine>();
    
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();

    var applicationLogger = serviceProvider.GetService<IApplicationLogger>();
    applicationLogger.LoggingSettings = applicationSetting.LoggingSetting;

    var signalR = serviceProvider.GetService<IHubContext<RfidHub>>();

    var applicationLogger = serviceProvider.GetService<IApplicationLogger>();
    applicationLogger.LoggingSettings = applicationSetting.LoggingSetting;

    var rfidEngine = serviceProvider.GetService<IRfidEngine>();
    rfidEngine.Start();
    
    applicationLogger.LogInformation($@"Program has started", LoggerType.Console);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors("ApplicationCors");
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHub<RfidHub>("/rfidhub");
    });
}
```

**Hub**

```
public class RfidHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendReadings(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveReading", user, message);
    }
}
```

**RfidEngine**

```
public class RfidEngine : IDisposable, IRfidEngine
{
    public RfidEngine(IApplicationLogger applicationLogger, IHubContext<RfidHub> hubContext)
    {
        this.applicationLogger = applicationLogger;
        this.hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    private void SendViaHub(string message)
    {
        hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveReadings", message);
    }
}
```

This is my version of Signalr:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="5.0.8" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I need to be able to call the `HubContext` on a different class. What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: The XML in this question was misformatted. The issue was that code blocks need a blank line above them in order to be formatted in Markdown correctly.